# How would I make my code which creates accounts safe from SQL-Injections?

Tags: python, sqlite, security, sql-injection

This is my code:

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accounts(name text primary key, password text)')
connection.commit()
connection.close()

continue_loop = True
yes_no_value = input("Would you like to create a new account? (yes/no): ")
if yes_no_value == 'no':
    continue_loop = False

while continue_loop:

    user = input("Enter username: ")
    password = input("Enter password: ")
    connection = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO accounts VALUES("{user}", "{password}")')
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
    print('success')
    yes_no_value = input("Would you like to create a new account? (yes/no): ")
    if yes_no_value == 'no':
        continue_loop == False
```

It would help if someone could send me my code but edited to be safe from SQL injections, and explain.

Comment: The bigger risk here is that you store the password in clear text. I am hoping that this is just an example and not production code.

Comment: This is not the actual one it is just an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you provided, the code that's at risk from injection is this line:

```
cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO accounts VALUES("{user}", "{password}")')
```

So, what you have to worry about is the safety of the values of `user` and `password` at that point. You're allowing the user to enter them from the console, so they could basically enter anything.

You could instead:

```
cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO accounts VALUES(?, ?)', (user, password))
```

This has the same result, but now `cursor.execute()` (or an underlying call) turns the values of `user` and `password` into the values for SQL and has a chance of catching shenanigans in the process.

Comment: Note that you could do further checking by performing your own tests on the values of `user` and `password` before passing them on, if relying on `cursor.execute()` isn't good enough.